# Jtable input format

Tags: java, jquery-jtable

What is the format in which jtable plugin needs input? Is this correct?

```
  {"Result":"OK","Records":[{"usecase_keyname":"Administration","activity_name":"folderAccess","tower_name":"Windows","is_custom_activity":"0","usecaseStatus_name":"InProgress"}]}
```

Comment: Jquery? Is this a Java or JavaScript question?

Comment: I'd guess that's a JavaScript/JQuery question and not a Java question. Besides that, isn't there a documentation on the plugin?